# Why am I not able to login to the admin

Tags: login, wp-login-form

After the login credentials are submitted, the login page is retained. There is no invalid username or password message. The URL changed from wp-admin to wp-login.php with the querystrings. The console on the browser inspector says The Cookie has been rejected because it is already expired.

Comment: Good debugging so far! That sounds like the site is trying to set a cookie for successful login but it's getting it wrong. If you log in with the browser debug tools open, what do you see for the main page request (wp-login.php, top in the network view) response headers (on the headers tab)? Is there a Set-Cookie there?

Comment: Best guess the time on your server is wrong.

Comment: Now the login is working. I guess there was something in the server..